# ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseContact'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem while running my Django code.

```
File "E:\sophienwald\amocrm\models.py", line 3, in <module>
from amocrm import BaseContact, amo_settings, fields, BaseLead
ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseContact'
```

But I noticed a strange feature... If I swap "BaseContact" and "BaseLead" it says that compiler can't import BaseLead. "fields" and "amo_setting" work fine.

Bit of code from amocrm\models.py:

```
import logging

from amocrm import BaseContact, amo_settings, fields, BaseLead
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import MultiFieldPanel, FieldPanel
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting
from wagtail.contrib.settings.registry import register_setting

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@register_setting
class AmocrmSettings(BaseSetting):
    PIPELINE_FIELDS = [
        ('stay_tuned_pipeline_name', 'stay_tuned_status_name'),
        ('new_posts_pipeline_name', 'new_posts_status_name'),
        ('back_call_pipeline_name', 'back_call_status_name'),
    ]

    login = models.CharField('Логин', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.CharField('Токен', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    subdomain = models.CharField('Поддомен', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    run_async = models.BooleanField('Обновлять асинхронно', default=False)

    # forms.StayTunedContact
    stay_tuned_pipeline_name = models.CharField('Название воронки', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    stay_tuned_status_name = models.CharField('Статус при создании', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    # forms.NewPostsContact
    new_posts_pipeline_name = models.CharField('Название воронки', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    new_posts_status_name = models.CharField('Статус при создании', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    # forms.BackCallContact
    back_call_pipeline_name = models.CharField('Название воронки', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    back_call_status_name = models.CharField('Статус при создании', max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('login'),
            FieldPanel('token'),
            FieldPanel('subdomain'),
            FieldPanel('run_async'),
        ], 'Авторизация'),
    ]
```

There is part of models.py with "BaseContact"

```
class Contact(BaseContact):
    """
    Amocrm package contact model with custom fields
    """
    phone = fields.EnumCustomField('Телефон', enum='WORK')
    email = fields.EnumCustomField('Email', enum='WORK')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'name: {self.name}, phone: {self.phone}, email: {self.email}'
```

Comment: Can you post the file where BaseContact is defined?

Comment: Added part of code with BaseContact